# Find all numbers in txt file

Tags: c, numbers, text-files

I have a text file within text and numbers.

I must make a function that finds all numbers from the text file.

I opened a file now what?

```
FILE *fp;
if((fp=fopen("Text.txt","r"))==NULL) {
    printf("No such file...\n");
}
```

Comment: Homework? What do you have so far?

Comment: try a bit of code from here first http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html and then post what you get. People will help you if you try.

Comment: @Omar that is not trying seriously. How about formulating a pseudo code approach first. So, just in natural language, how would you proceed from hereon?

Comment: Okey just tell me how can i use function like getchar in a file ?

Comment: @Omar you cannot use `getchar()` for files. The manpage states that it is used to get a character from `stdin`, which is terminal input. Try `fgetc`, more info: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgetc/

Answer (score 8):

I'm sure it is homework.

Define what is lexically a number for you (it is too imprecise).

Then make a loop, reading line by line with e.g. `getline` or character by character.

Read more about [lexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexing) and [automata based programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata-based_programming)

But I don't want to do all your homework. It is better for you to try understanding by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Open the first file for reading. Open another file for writing. Iterate over characters, determining whether each "word" is a number or not using `atof`, and if it is a number, write to the open file.

Same could be done with just outputting, but that's not as interesting.

EDIT: Basile Starynkevitch mentions that `strtod` is better than `atof` for this job, as it gives the ending character. Both work.

Comment: `strtod` is better, it gives you the ending character.

Comment: I do not think that this works. From the manpage: 

On success, the function returns the converted floating point number as a double value.
If no valid conversion could be performed, or if the correct value would cause underflow, a zero value (0.0) is returned. (source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/)

How would you differentiate between the word "0" and "monkey"?

(pff 10 edits later:)
After this check passed, you need to check if all characters c fulfill: '0' <= c <= '9'